# How can I optimize this query to get result from it faster?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query, that I execute a lot of times. Can you please suggest how to optimize this? Indexes are already applied to the table.

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT b.appearance_id,
    b.photo_album_id,
    b.eventcmmnt_id,
    b.id,
    b.mem_id,
    b.subj,
    b.body,
    b.date,
    b.parentid,
    b.from_id,
    b.visible_to,
    b.image_link,
    b.post_via,
    b.youtubeLink,
    b.link_image,
    b.link_url,
    b.auto_genrate_text
FROM
    bulletin b
INNER JOIN
    network n
ON
    ( n.mem_id = b.mem_id )
WHERE
    b.parentid = '0' AND 
    '$userid' IN (n.frd_id, b.mem_id))
GROUP BY
    b.id
ORDER BY
    b.date DESC
LIMIT
    0,20
```

Comment: starting point: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-explain.html

Comment: What is the GROUP BY b.id exactly for? You don't seem to use any aggregates. "Group by" can be expensive. Asside from that: make sure you index all columns you join on.

Comment: Increase query cache size perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are `network.frd_id`, `network.mem_id` and `bulletin.mem_id` all indexed? If they are not, you will be in chaos if there are some larger volumes in the tables.

Also, `and ('$userid' IN (n.frd_id, b.mem_id))` is terrible in terms of cost. If possible you should always stick to `=`, `!=` and the like. Is it possible to replace this line with `and ('$userid' = n.frd_id or '$userid = b.mem_id)` ?

Lastly, if you are looking at some serious volumes in terms of records, re-ordering the table may be a big win for you. I run some heavish databases at work which contain large volumes of data identified by a key value. Normally, I want to aggregate these values up to some level. I have found that running an occasional `alter table someTableName order by col1, col2;` to group the records into the chunks that are likely to be aggregated or sifted through together makes a drastic improvement.

Comment: @user1551419 Added another section on re-ordering the table.